# What's causing my Lenovo Z51 to BSOD?

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I could use some help analyzing DMP files that were generated after 4-5 BSOD crashes on my laptop. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KTqHH57cDLABcds_XhnMoYP3r7s5Tm-6?usp=sharing

Since BSODs started happening, I updated the BIOS, reinstalled graphics drivers, removed Avast. I also disabled the secondary GPU. For now, the system is BSOD free.

If there is a chance that BSODs were hardware related, maybe some of you will notice that in the DMP files.

Output of WhoCrashed:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please open the `.dmp` file with a tool such as WhoCrashed, and show a screenshot. I'm not downloading some random file from some random Google drive account.

Comment: Here are the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/D3ib2Rz

Comment: That looks terminal. I would suggest a Memtest86 soak-test over a few hours to check your RAM, and an `sfc /scannow` to see if anything file-system based is corrupt.